# How do I prove that a unique solution exists in a region $D$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the differential equation below:
 $$\frac{dy}{dx}= xe^{-y^2}, \;    y(1)=e $$    and 
$D = \{(x, y) : x, y \in\mathbb{R}, 1 \le x \le 2\}$.

Determine if the differential equation will have a unique solution on $D$. Support your answer.

I know that the derivative function is continuous and $1$ is in $D$. So there must be a unique solution on $D$. However, I don't know how to formally write the proof in a detailed way and to mathematically show it with theorems and equations such as Lipschitz condition and successive approximations if necessary. Please can you help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem)?

Comment: I have heard of that before but I just read about it. However, the differential equation cannot easily be solved and it is not separable. How can I go about proving with Picard/successive approximation?

Comment: Sorry, it is separable but it is not easy to solve the ODE directly.

Comment: Can someone please help me use the picard theorem to solve it?